# Is it possible to display a results array in a defined number of columns using only client side scripting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array of images/links that need to be displayed in columns of 8 for however many rows there are, but I can not control this array.

Is it possible to format this using CSS/HTML (or as a last resort Javascript) so that a new row is created after x items is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its very possible by using a fix sized container and css float property.

for e.g.

```
<div style="width:600px;">
      <div style="width:200px;float:left;"  >
          your data here
   </div>
</div>
```

You can create the similar code using javascript. Iterate throught the inner div container and after the 600px limit it will automatically start a new line.

Comment: Remember to pay attention to margins and borders of the inner div and the padding of the containing one.